# ASP.NET WebForms application trying to create a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Why is my WebForms app accessing entity framework to create a database?  I have removed all references to EF in my code and web.config.  I'm trying to use InProc session state.  But when my session expires or the app pool recycles any calls from the browser result in a long spin and ultimately an exception from EF trying to create a database.  (see below)

> ```
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>
>  Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> Source Error: 
>
>
>  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
>
> Stack Trace: 
>
>
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +830
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +329
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +682
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +217
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
>    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.c__DisplayClass33.b__32() +426
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +10
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +556
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +86
>    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +164
>    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +76
>    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
>    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +119
>    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
>    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +89
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
>    System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +218
>    System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +151
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e() +76
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c) +7
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
>    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +53
>    System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +34
>    System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues) +26
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.EntityStore`1.GetByIdAsync(Object id) +49
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__6c.MoveNext() +163
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.b__1>d__4.MoveNext() +909
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +11532712
>    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.d__2.MoveNext() +2151
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +581
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +225
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +409
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +409
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +409
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext() +187
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext() +185
>    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
>    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
>    System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
>    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
>
>
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0
> ```

Comment: any chance you're referencing another project that has a reference to entity framework?  Newer version of asp.net identity use entity framework.  Can you post a copy of your packages.config?

Comment: I am referencing asp.net identity.  What is it trying to do?

Comment: create a database to store users, roles and all of the other aspnet_ tables that it uses.  It's only the newer versions that use entity framework, I'll see if I can dig up a version number.

Comment: looks like the visual studio 2013 and after,  https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Okay, cool.  That's very likely my problem.  If you can post that as an answer I'll give you credit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you're referencing another project that has a reference to entity framework? Newer version of asp.net identity use entity framework.

Comment: Thank you for your help!